# Why am I getting a 'class expected' error when placing a value into an array slot?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to this website so I barely a clue on how to use it, I tried, I'm sorry if I've made mistakes. My program intakes ten integer values and places them in an array, then displays the contents of the array in reverse. I keep receiving an error that states:

> ReverseIntegers.java:23: class expected

Here's the code that it says is having the issue:

> IntValues[number1] = int.parseInt (UserInput)

And here is the full code I've written:

```
class ReverseIntegers
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String UserInput, Integers;
        int number1 = 9;
        int[] IntValues = new int[10];
        InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader (System.in);
        BufferedReader num = new BufferedReader (inStream);
        System.out.println ("Enter ten integer values and the program will display them in reverse order.");
        while (number1 > -1)
        {
            UserInput = num.readLine();
            IntValues[number1] = int.parseInt (UserInput);
            System.out.println (number1 + " numbers are left to be entered, please continue.");
            number1--;
        }
        number1 = 0;
        System.out.println ("The numbers entered in reverse order are: ");
        while (number1 < 10)
        {
            System.out.println (IntValues[number1]);
            number1++;
        }
    }
}
```

Help! I don't know what the problem is!

Comment: I removed the `javascript` tag as this question has nothing to do with Javascript - Java and Javascript are entirely different languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `int.parseInt(UserInput)`, you want `Integer.parseInt(UserInput)`. The `Integer` class is the corresponding `Object` class for the primitive type `int`. This method that you are trying to access, `parseInt(String value)`, is within that `Integer` class.

The error you are recieving makes sense, as `int` doesn't have any methods as it is a primitive type. It is telling you that you are trying to call a method from a primitive type, and that instead, a class is expected to be calling a method.

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked, I completely forgot about that. How do I mark this question as answered, by the way?

Comment: @Slash there should be a checkmark next to my answer that you can click to mark the question as answered. And no problem!